# What is the return type of a function returning a range?

Tags: c++, range-v3, return-type-deduction

This function can be compiled as is. `auto` works well here. But what would the explicit return type of such a function be?

```
auto rangeTest()
    {
        static const std::vector<int> vi{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        auto rng = vi | ranges::view::remove_if([](int i){return i % 2 == 1;})
                | ranges::view::transform([](int i){return std::to_string(i);});
        return rng;
    }
```

Comment: "Such a function" is a general concept. The range library has own classes. In this case I would expect `return std::to_string(i)` predicts the return type.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it's a fair question. If I use gdb to watch the type of `rng`, that the line is longer that a comment could be (and definitely not a `string`). If I would need to give an explicit type to this function, it would be really "inconvenient".

Comment: It would be something like `transform_view<remove_if_view<const std::vector<int>, rangeTest::Lambda1>, rangeTest::Lambda2>`.

Comment: The trick to get type from compiler is `template <typename T> struct Debug; template struct Debug<decltype(rangeTest())>; /* explicit instantiation of class without definition. */`.

Comment: @dani yeah, some people just down vote because they don't understand the question. Happens a lot here I've noticed.

Comment: A question that is not understandable is a bad question. Bad question => vote down (if lazy) or edit. I have edited it.

Comment: **Pro-Tip**: Just assign the return value to something incompatible and decrypt the `No conversion from ${your type} to ${...}` compiler error.